# Can someone please let me know what are the jar files and import libraries needed for YouTube APIs to get view count

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, youtube, youtube-api

I am trying find out view count for a YouTube video from YouTube API and found some code to do so. But I am unable to compile the code as it needs jar files and import libraries. Please help.

```
YouTube youtube = new YouTube.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), new HttpRequestInitializer());

YouTube.Videos.List videoRequest = youtube.videos().list("contentDetails");
videoRequest.setId("SOME-VIDEO-ID");
videoRequest.setFields("items/contentDetails");
videoRequest.setKey("YOUR-API-KEY");
VideoListResponse response = videoRequest.execute(); //blocking call, ensure to perform off ui thread via AsyncTask 
List<Video> videosList = response.getItems(); 

if(videosList != null && videosList.size() > 0){
 Video video = videosList.get(0);
 VideoStatistics statistics = video.getStatistics();
 BigInteger viewCount = statistics.getViewCount();
}
```

Error Below: 
Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:assembleDebug]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.1 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.1 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72310Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72310Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42310Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDexDebug
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"trouble processing \"javax/transaction/HeuristicCommitException.class\":","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"when not building a core library.","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"in your application\u0027s project, when using an IDE (such as","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"Eclipse). If you are sure you\u0027re not intentionally defining a","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"core class, then this is the most likely explanation of what\u0027s","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"going on.","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"However, you might actually be trying to define a class in a core","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"namespace, the source of which you may have taken, for example,","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"from a non-Android virtual machine project. This will most","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"assuredly not work. At a minimum, it jeopardizes the","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"compatibility of your app with future versions of the platform.","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"It is also often of questionable legality.","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"If you really intend to build a core library -- which is only","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"appropriate as part of creating a full virtual machine","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"distribution, as opposed to compiling an application -- then use","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"the \"--core-library\" option to suppress this error message.","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"If you go ahead and use \"--core-library\" but are in fact","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"building an application, then be forewarned that your application","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"will still fail to build or run, at some point. Please be","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"prepared for angry customers who find, for example, that your","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"application ceases to function once they upgrade their operating","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"system. You will be to blame for this problem.","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"If you are legitimately using some code that happens to be in a","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"core package, then the easiest safe alternative you have is to","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"repackage that code. That is, move the classes in question into","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"your own package namespace. This means that they will never be in","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"conflict with core system classes. JarJar is a tool that may help","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"you in this endeavor. If you find that you cannot do this, then","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"that is an indication that the path you are on will ultimately","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"lead to pain, suffering, grief, and lamentation.","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"1 error; aborting","sources":[{}]}

FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.

  > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Comment: What is the error? What is the question?

Comment: The Question is what are the jar files needed and libs needed to import: 'Error:(353, 93) error: HttpRequestInitializer is abstract; cannot be instantiated Error:(353, 27) error: incompatible types required: YouTube found: Builder Error:(359, 9) error: cannot find symbol class VideoListResponse Error:(364, 11) error: cannot find symbol class VideoStatistics'

Comment: please update your question with the full stacktrace instead of posting in comments =)

Comment: also, the error says that `HttpRequestInitializer` is abstract and cannot be instantiated:  `new HttpRequestInitializer()` will not work. Check for implemetations of this class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is what I am using currently (on gradle build)

```
    compile('com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev144-1.20.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'
    }
```

just paste the line into the build.gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

I think the libraries you are after are these:

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/youtube/v3

might need to read this as well to cover the android setup

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/android

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve the errors by adding only required jar files:
1) YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar
2) google-api-services-youtube-v3-rev152-1.21.0.jar
3) google-http-client-android-1.20.0.jar
4) google-api-client-android-1.20.0.jar

Build Gradle File

```
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev152-1.21.0'
```